AR Flutter Plugin Issue: Class Names and Methods Not Found in ar_flutter_plugin_flutterflow
I'm having trouble using the ar_flutter_plugin_flutterflow package in my Flutter project. I followed the installation instructions and updated my pubspec.yaml with the correct package version:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  ar_flutter_plugin_flutterflow: ^0.7.47
  vector_math: ^2.1.0 ```

I imported the package in my main.dart file using:

```import 'package:ar_flutter_plugin_flutterflow/ar_flutter_plugin.dart';```

However, I’m encountering issues with class names and methods not being recognized. Specifically:

Class Names and Methods: The classes and methods I’m using are not recognized by the Flutter editor. For example, I’ve used:
ArSessionManager (I expected ArCoreController or similar)
ArView (I expected ArCoreView or similar)
Methods like addArNode() do not seem to exist.

[here is a screenshot](https://i.sstatic.net/JVcBJ2C9.png)

Question:
Are there updates or changes to the classes and methods in ar_flutter_plugin_flutterflow that differ from the original ar_flutter_plugin? How can I adapt my code to match the updated API, or is there another approach I should take to resolve these issues?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Added the correct package dependency in pubspec.yaml.
Ran flutter pub get and restarted the environment.

